# Trouble with vpnc in Linux Mint 13

Tags: vpnc

After a fressh install of Linux Mint 13, I tried to connect to a VPN with the vpnc client, and received the following error message:

> resolvconf: Error: /etc/resolv.conf isn't a symlink, not doing
>   anything.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to run

> sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf

This generates the link /etc/resolv.conf, which then fixes the error listed above.